# Func and List<string>

Tags: c#

I have defined the following

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string, List<string>>> test1 = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, List<string>>>();
```

also I have

```
    private string fred(List<string> Parms)
    {

        return "Test";
    }
```

how do I add fred to the dictionary? 
I have tried

```
       test1.Add("Test",fred);
```

but I get an error, if I replace the List for a string everything is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the arguments around the wrong way. A `Func<X,Y>` takes an `X` and returns a `Y`. Your dictionary should be:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<List<string>,string>>
```

Comment: No problem :) This also generalizes - for `Func` the last parameter is always the return type; `Func<X,Y,Z>` takes an `X` and a `Y` and returns a `Z`.

Comment: I should look at the intellisense more. I assumed it was same way as a function definition, the return type is first.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string, List<string>>> test1 = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, List<string>>>();
```

should be

```
Dictionary<string, Func<List<string>, string>>> test1 = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<string>, string>>();
```